# Create object similar to Number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, numbers

How to create a new primitive or object where I can use the operators used in Number?

I want to create a new object like Number, with a different name, another properties and where I can to use the operators i.e. 4+5

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why can't you just use a number?

Comment: Because I want to have different names according its size, i.e. for integers of 8, 16 or 32 bits; the same for unsigned integers

Comment: You can't override operators in JS.

Comment: Then, my better option is object inheritance to Number.

Comment: Don't know if that will help you. As soon as you use these operators your objects will either be converted (see David's answer) or simple won't work in math operations. Even if they can be converted, they will never be converted back to whatever they were before (e.g. your derived type).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override an objects `valueOf` prototype to create your own primitive:

```
var N = function(n) {
    this._value = n;
}
N.prototype.valueOf = function() {
    return this._value+1;
};
console.log( new N(4) + 4 ); // 9
```

See examples and more info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Number object if you want it specifically for a number. If you want it for something else and are only using Number as an example, you can't do it because JavaScript doesn't support operator overloading.

Your best best is chaining together by returning `this` in the `plus` function, so you could do:

```
var n1 = new MyNumber(1);
var n2 = new MyNumber(2);
var n3 = new MyNumber(3);
var sum = n1.plus(n2).plus(n3);

// sum: 6
```

You'd also have to make sure that `MyNumber` creates a new `MyNumber` and returns that, unless you want mutable numbers.